# How to pass directive parameters to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Need your help. I would like to use my custom directive with parameters like this:

```
<p customImage URL_PARAM="some_url.jpg" FIG_PARAM="Fig 1."></p>
```

My target is to use the directive parameters in the template like this:

```
.directive('customImage', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: '<div> <img src="URL_PARAM"> FIG_PARAM </div>'
    };
});
```

How to make this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you need, you usually want to create a sibling scope for the directive (that is, a scope that lives out of the normal hierarchical scope, inheriting the upper levels) to allow multiple directive to live within the same level without affecting each other's properties. If you have a look at AngularJS [documentation entry for directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), under directive definition object, you can see three different property binding you can specify in your directive's scope definition. Take this scope definition of your directive, as an example:

```
scope: { 
  urlParamAttr: '@URL_PARAM', 
  urlParamEval: '=URL_PARAM', 
  urlParamFn:'&URL_PARAM' 
}
```

- @ / @name: This definition will bind an attribute's plain value to the directive scope. In the example, a `urlParamAttr` property on your directive scope will be bound to the directive's `URL_PARAM` plain HTML attribute. This will always be a string as a HTML attribute is a text node and will have the value of `some_url.jpg`
- = / =name: This will bind the evaluation of the attribute in the context of the defining scope to a property on your directive's scope. In the example, Angular will try to evaluate `some_url.jpg` and will fail as it is not valid javascript. If the directive have an attribute value of `'some_url.jpg'`, it will be evaluated as a string (because of the quotes). If the scope defining your directive has a property called `imageUrl` with a value of `some_url.jpg` (a string) and the directive `URL_PARAM` has the value `imageUrl`, Angular will bind your directive's property to the declaring scope `imageUrl` property and update it as it changes in a digest cycle.
- & / &name: This definition will bind an attribute property and treat it as a function that you directive can call.For example, if you directive has an `on-click` property, a user could put a custom function from another scope that will be called from the directive's scope.

In your case, you can treat the attribute as plain HTML (and you can change it depending on your needs) and change your template to bind to the directive's scope properties:

```
.directive('customImage', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            urlParam: '@URL_PARAM',
            figParam: '@FIG_PARAM'
        },
        template: '<div> <img src="{{urlParam}}"/> {{figParam}} </div>'
    };
});
```